# Hibernate : Retrieve objects using Restrictions

Tags: java, hibernate

I recently started using hibernate with java.

I have an Entity Staff like this :

```
final public class Staff {
@Id @GeneratedValue
private int staffId;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String Email;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "auth_id", nullable = false)
private Authentication auth;
//And all the getters and setters
}
```

My Authentication class :

```
final public class Authentication {

@Id @GeneratedValue
@Column(name="auth_id")
private int authId;
private String pwd;
private String secretQuestion;
private String secretAnswer;
//And all the getters and setters
}
```

For a login I need to check the email and password. So i created a Hash Map :

```
Map<String, String> requirements = 
            new HashMap<String, String>();
            requirements.put("Email", "example@example.com");
                requirements.put("auth.pwd", "password");
```

Then ran the query :

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(currentClass);
            criteria.add(Restrictions.allEq(requirements));
staffList = (ArrayList<Staff>) criteria.list();
```

But I get this Exception :

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: auth.pwd of: models.Staff
```

My question is : How do we set restrictions for entities inside an Entity?

If I have left out any other information which I am supposed to mention, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by restrictions?

Comment: @orique Well after reading the documentation what I understood was its used along with Hibernate Criteria to retrieve info from the database.

Comment: thanks, I was reviewing posts and probably I missed some information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use alias for `auth` property of `Staff` entity:

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Staff.class, "staff");
crit.createAlias("auth", "a");  // Create alias for auth
crit.add(Restrictions.like("a.propertyName", propertyValue+"%"));
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly. I managed to get this working :
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(currentClass).createAlias("auth","a");
            criteria.add(Restrictions.allEq(requirements));